# How to get http://mysite.com/ indexed in a search engine, not http://mysite.com/index.php, and nothing more?

Tags: html, seo, robots.txt

In only one search engine I want to get...

```
http://mysite.com/
```

indexed,
not...

```
http://mysite.com/index.php
```

I only want to allow indexing of the
main page of the website, and nothing more.  I do not want the bot to
follow any of the links on the main page.

My meta tags include the following::

```
<meta name="robots" content="index, nofollow" />
```

My robot.txt includes the following::

```
User-agent: Googlebot
Allow: /index.php
Disallow: /

User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

Will this achieve my desired result?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: belongs on http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   !^www\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   !^$
RewriteRule ^/(.*)         http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Put this in **.htaccess**.

This is straight from [Apache's URL Rewriting Guide](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html)

Answer (score 1):

Specify your canonical:

From http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2009/02/specify-your-canonical.html

```
<link rel="canonical" href="http://www.mysite.com/" />
```

in your `<head>`